# delphi CopyMemory from index

Tags: delphi, memory, copy

I am using Delphi 7. Could you tell me if there is or can be found somewhere a procedure
which acts like: CopyMemory but I would be able to copy memory from 
the specific number of byte.

I need something with the following signature:

```
procedure CopyMemory(Destination: Pointer; Source: Pointer; Length: DWORD; fromByte: Integer);
```

I need this, because I have to send unsent bytes over tcpip and that's the reason why I have to extract unsent bytes stored in the memory.

I have looked in the source and I would need to rewrite a little asm section.
I have not touched asm for years and I would rather stay with something reliable ..

Thanks!

Comment: Thank You all for your help! The solution was so simple and obvious. I forgot about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure CopyMemory(Src, Dest: Pointer; Len: Cardinal; Offset: Integer);
var
  OffsetSrc: ^Byte;
begin
  OffsetSrc := Src;
  inc(OffsetSrc, Offset);
  Move(OffsetSrc^, Dest^, Len);
end;
```

But I think I'd probably prefer to do the pointer arithmetic outside a helper function.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this:

```
procedure CopyMemory(Destination: Pointer; Source: Pointer; Length, fromByte: Integer);
begin
  move(PAnsiChar(Source)[frombyte],PAnsichar(Dest)[frombyte],Length-fromByte);
end;
```

And don't rewrite the moving part.
Rely on the VCL version.
Or use the [FastCode version](http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/) if you need.

Comment: @Johann Thanks for the FastCode link! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could still use CopyMemory, just use the address of the fist unsent byte as the source pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the address of the first byte you want to copy. Make sure you adjust the length.

**Pseudocode**:

```
var
  Dest   : TBytes;
  Source : TBytes;
...
SetLength (Dest, Length (Source) - FromByte);
CopyMemory (@Dest[0], @Source[FromByte], Length (Source) - FromByte);
```